# Python datatype suitable for my cache

Tags: python

I'm searching for the a datatype for a cache, basically I need the functionality of a dict, i.e. random access based on a key, which has a limited number of entries so that when the limit is reached the oldest item gets automatically removed.
Furthermore I need to be able to store it via shelve or pickle and rely on Python 2.4.
Should I subclass dict and add a list to it? Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I have not mentioned the scale, I need to keep track of already read items which consist of a signature by which they are identified and I only want to keep track of about a few hundred of them.
collections.deque seem nice but that's a list and I need random access. So dict would seem suitable, however somehow I need to expire items if the limit is hit which means I need to keep track the order in which they have been added.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered the question yourself. You need to subclass a dict. And you also of course needs to have a list of the keys, so when the list gets too long you can purge the oldest one.

I would however possibly look into memcached or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an LRU cache (one where "oldest" is measured by "least recently accessed" as opposed to "least recently obtained") -- for most access patterns it performs MUCH better than a naive "oldest goes first" cache (an extremely popular item may easily be the oldest one obtained, but half the recent hits go to it -- how silly to evict it just because it was obtained a long time ago, when it's SO popular!-). Read up on caching in general at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms).

LRU is tricky to program in solid and well-performing ways; I recommend you download, install and reuse [lrucache](http://evan.prodromou.name/Software/Python/LRUCache) instead. If it doesn't match all of your needs exactly, it's easier to tweak existing code than to start from scratch on a tricky subject.

Comment: Well it is for a web feeds where new items are quickly added and require me to expire old items from my seen items list to limit its size. So such sophisticated caching seems overkill, I'd rather have something more simple, something like a dict of let's say 100 items which keeps track of when an item was added and simply discards the oldest one when the 101st item gets added. But maybe that's more complicated to implement than I expected.